# Longitude Latitude on Flask WTF Forms

Tags: python, google-maps, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I am trying to get the Flask WTF form to read longitude and latitude, but I can't find the proper form field for it. I found some examples where FloatField is used successfully, but the example are really old and I presume there have been changes in the WTF forms.

Here is the Form class I am using:

```
class GetFieldForm(Form):
    field_name = StringField(Designation')
    field_latitude = FloatField(u'Latitude', default=-30, validators=[InputRequired()], description='48.182601')
    field_longitude = FloatField(u'Longitude', default=150,
                                 validators=[InputRequired()], description='11.304939')
    submit = SubmitField(u'Signup')
```

Passing the values from the form to the Google Maps:

```
@frontend.route('/demo')
def demo():
        field_form = GetFieldForm()
        if field_form.validate_on_submit():
            flash('Hello, {}. You have successfully signed up'
                  .format(escape(field_form.name.data)))

            field_latitude = field_form.field_latitude.data
            field_longitude = field_form.field_longitude.data
            mymap = Map(
                identifier="view-side",
                lat=field_latitude,
                lng=field_longitude,
                zoom=18,
                style="height:720px;width:720px;margin:0;",  # hardcoded!
                markers=[(field_latitude, field_longitude)],
                maptype='SATELLITE'
            )

            return render_template('demo.html', mymap=mymap, field_form=field_form)
```

With the following Jinja2 template:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="row-fluid">

                <div id="map" class="col-md-7">
                    {{mymap.html}}
                </div>

               <div class="col-md-5">
                   <div class="panel panel-default">
                <!-- Panel Title -->
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h2 class="panel-title text-center">Locate Your Field  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span></h2>

                 <div class="panel-body">
                 {% if request.args.get('legacy') -%}
                   {{wtf.quick_form(field_form, novalidate=True)}}
                 {%- else -%}
                   {{field_form|render_form()}}
                 {%- endif %}
                     </div>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The problem is, that the form doesn't allow me to pass longitude and latitude as floats:
[image]

Versions I am using:

Flask 0.12

Flask-WTF 0.14.2

Flask-GoogleMaps  https://github.com/rochacbruno/Flask-GoogleMaps

EDIT: Got a hint that I the error may have something to do with FLASK-Bootstrap>

> The problem is Flask-Bootstrap, that you seem to be using.
>   https://github.com/mbr/flask-bootstrap/blob/master/flask_bootstrap/forms.py#L97-L99
>   It overrides the float type to use "number" as input type, which is
>   not quite right there, since "number" in html5 is limited to integers
>   if the step argument is not provided. So you have to set the step
>   attribute on your input field, though I don't know how to do that with
>   Flask-Bootstrap. Preferably something like step="0.000001" should
>   suffice.

But how would I pass the step parameter is beyond me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. 
Instead of generating the form like this:

```
{{field_form|render_form()}}
```

do this:

```
{{wtf.quick_form(field_form, novalidate=True)}}
```